# Dual-Boot Ubuntu with Windows 10 when using 3 drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I currently have 3 drives on my PC: An m.2 SSD (with windows currently installed on it), a SATA SSD, and a HDD. I'm looking to install Ubuntu onto a partition on the SATA SSD, but I am worried about the bootloader location when installing. I have the option to install the bootloader to the SATA SSD (/dev/sda) or the m.2 (/dev/nvme0). Does it matter which location I install the bootloader to, or am I doing something wrong already?

I don't have the option to "install ubuntu alongside windows 10" for the SATA SSD, only the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the installer, so grub gets written to the first EFI (on  sda) regardless of what you specify as a location.  See bugs 1173457,1396379,1702335.
This may not matter to you since your disks are not removable(?).  If you want the hdd to be separately bootable, make sure you manually add an EFI partition, then after the install, just copy the contents of the sdd's EFI to the hdd's.

---

Grub installed on a device is able to boot other devices, so you will be able to boot Windows.

Comment: The assumption is you are installing in UEFI boot mode, and if Windows is UEFI, you should. Some suggest disconnecting other drives so it only installs to the drive you want. Or in UEFI settings turn drives to disabled. You do need to partition in advance. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation
&  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it be ok to install it on sda even though that is not where Windows is installed to?